# C# SQLite parameterized queries fail to include parameter value

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-framework-version, system.data.sqlite

I'm attempting to rework some SQLite queries that I'm making in the my application to use parameters instead of concatenating a string, to make sure that my code is not prone to SQL injection attacks and is more robust in general.
However, I'm failing to get any parameterized queries to successfully execute in my application. I've browsed countless examples and related questions and none have helped.

My sample code :

```
string connectionString = @"Datasource=C:\Users\me\source\repos\sample\bin\Debug\Logs\Log.db3";
        string commandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS @tablename (Timestamp TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(STRFTIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'NOW')), Loglevel TEXT, Callsite TEXT, Message TEXT);";
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SQLiteCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", "Service");
                comm.CommandText = commandText;
                int value = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

When I execute the above code manually in DBBrowser for SQLite, replacing '@tablename' with Service as I'd like to do programatically, the query works fine and inserts the table as it should.

However, when I execute the code, I get the following exception :

```
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException
  HResult=0x800007BF
  Message=SQL logic error
near "@tablename": syntax error
  Source=System.Data.SQLite
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(SQLiteConnection cnn, String strSql, SQLiteStatement previous, UInt32 timeoutMS, String& strRemain)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(Int32 index)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SqliteParametersTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\me\source\repos\SqliteParametersTest\SqliteParametersTest\Program.cs:line 23

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection, string, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteStatement, uint, ref string)
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.BuildNextCommand()
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.GetStatement(int)
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.SQLiteDataReader(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand, System.Data.CommandBehavior)
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(System.Data.CommandBehavior)
    System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    SqliteParametersTest.Program.Main(string[]) in Program.cs
```

When I modify my code to omit the '@' character in front of the parameter name, the code executes successfully, but performs the query ***without*** parameterizing it - IE despite changing the parameter name that I pass in from '@tablename' to 'tablename', the query that gets execute is :

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename(...

I have a feeling at this point that there is a deeper underlying issue that is causing this, maybe to do with .NET Framework 4.5 version that I've selected for this sample project. System.Data.Sqlite library version being used is 1.0.115.

Comment: Are you sure sqlite allows you parameterize the table name?

Comment: sqlite DOES NOT allow you to use parameters for identifiers

Comment: Please define 'identifier', that is a very generic term. Does the table name in the query fall under this category?

Comment: I don't know about SQLite, but SQL Server will not allow you to parameterize table names.  Consider using a preprocessor of some sort that does a limited token replace capability (using a syntax other than `@tableName`, perhaps something like `$(tableName)`)

Comment: In  https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html table-name is not an expression where bind-parameter is mentioned in expression: https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html. The syntax doesn't allow a bind-parameter for a table-name.

Comment: Thank you for the details...so the main question then is : how would one programatically check/create tables, while also adhering to the rule of not concatenating a SQL query string in the programming language of choice? Is this an exception to that rule, because there is no other choice? I could think of many scenarios where it just is not possible to hardcode a table name.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in the documentation for the CREATE TABLE function (or any other function where a table name identifier is required) is it clearly mentioned that the table name cannot be parameterized : https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html.

Admittedly, this issue also comes down to me having improperly designed my SQLite database, thus causing me to have to use unsupported features such as this.

In my case, I realized that I had created 3 different tables in my database with almost identical structures, originally with the intent that each one of my services would insert rows of data into each of the tables (which had the same name as the service itself), so that I could separate messages in the logging database.

I believe that the proper course of action for correcting this issue and ensuring that I do not have to encounter this issue and not exposing my code to SQL injection attacks by way of sending fully exposed SQL queries, is :

- consolidate identical column names into 1 table

  - instead of having a column 'DateTime' and 'Message' in 3 separate tables with separate table names -> 1 common table, with 'DateTime' and 'Message' columns
- create an additional column that identifies which one of my 3 services created that particular row in my DB, so that I can achieve the original intent of being able to identify where each separate 'Message' is coming from